# C++ unresolved external symbol in test phase of maven nar plugin

Tags: c++, maven, maven-plugin

I have a C++ Maven NAR project with different dependencies, my `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.image</groupId>
    <artifactId>image</artifactId>
    <packaging>nar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <name>Maven NAR Executable Project</name>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.10</version>
            <type>nar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv-highgui</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.10</version>
            <type>nar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>nar</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>integration-test</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
                <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <libraries>
                        <library>
                            <type>static</type>
                        </library>
                    </libraries>
                    <tests>
                        <test>
                            <name>NativeLibTest</name>
                            <link>static</link>
                        </test>
                    </tests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn compile` the project compiles successfully.

The problem arises when I use `mvn test -X`:

```
[INFO] --- nar-maven-plugin:3.2.3:nar-testCompile (default-nar-testCompile) @ image ---
...
[DEBUG] Examining artifact for NarInfo: org.opencv:opencv-core:nar:2.4.10:compile
[DEBUG]     - added as NarDependency
[DEBUG] Examining artifact for NarInfo: org.opencv:opencv-highgui:nar:2.4.10:compile
[DEBUG]     - added as NarDependency
[DEBUG] Examining artifact for NarInfo: my.commons:commons:nar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]     - added as NarDependency
...
[DEBUG] Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'link' with arguments:
'/MANIFEST'
'/NOLOGO'
'/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE'
'/INCREMENTAL:NO'
'/OUT:NativeLibTest.exe'
'E:\PROY\image-lib\dev\1.0\image\target\nar\image-1.0-x86-Windows-msvc-static\lib\x86-Windows-msvc\static\image-1.0.lib'
'E:\PROY\image-lib\dev\1.0\image\target\test-nar\opencv-core-2.4.10-x86-Windows-msvc-shared\lib\x86-Windows-msvc\shared\opencv-core-2.4.10.lib'
'E:\PROY\image-lib\dev\1.0\image\target\test-nar\opencv-highgui-2.4.10-x86-Windows-msvc-shared\lib\x86-Windows-msvc\shared\opencv-highgui-2.4.10.lib'
'E:\PROY\image-lib\dev\1.0\image\target\test-nar\obj\x86-Windows-msvc\image-test.obj'
```

From the messages *it appears to me that Maven NAR plugin is ignoring some libraries* (`my.commons`), that is strange because `my.commons` is added as NarDependency (as you can see in the first lines), even `target\test-nar\commons-1.0-x86-Windows-msvc-static\lib\x86-Windows-msvc\static` gets copied and has `commons-1.0.lib`. Finally the library isn't passed to `link` causing a lot of unresolved external symbols.

TLDR: Maven NAR compiles successfully when using `mvn compile` but fails when using `mvn test`.

**Update**

I think my other dependencies are getting injected because they are "Library Directories". A library directory is a project that contain a library (.lib in my case) in the directory tree `src\nar\resources\aol\x86-Windows-msvc\lib` and its corresponding headers in `src\nar\resources\noarch`. The term "library directory" can be found in the plugin's code (see NarTestCompileMoo.java:284). There are some comments about why libraries must be linked in test phase:

> ```
>   **NarTestCompileMoo.java:273**
>   // Static libraries should be linked. Even though the libraries
>   // themselves will have been tested already, the test code could
>   // use methods or classes defined in them.
> ```

So, why my static library is not getting recognized?

*Update*

I am realizing that I am using the version 3.2.3 when there is the version 3.3.0 http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.github.maven-nar%22%20AND%20a%3A%22nar-maven-plugin%22. So I will update and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is somewhat related to:

- [Maven NAR plugin lots of errors in Windows.h when updating to 3.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903652/maven-nar-plugin-lots-of-errors-in-windows-h-when-updating-to-3-3-0)
- [Maven NAR Plugin: Compiler errors in a simple program that uses Windows.h in version 3.3.0](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/issues/217)

So the solution applies here too. In a nutshell:

1. You need to use the last version of the Maven NAR Plugin.
2. As GregDomjan states on github, you need to configure your tools accordingly, in my case (msvc11.0/winsdk8.0):

*pom.xml*

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
            <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <libraries>
                    <library>
                        <type>executable</type>
                        <run>true</run>
                    </library>
                </libraries>
                <msvc>
                    <version>11.0</version>
                    <windowsSdkVersion>8.0</windowsSdkVersion>
                </msvc>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```