# Maven NAR plugin lots of errors in Windows.h when updating to 3.3.0

Tags: c++, maven, maven-plugin

There is this simple program:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32")
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    MessageBox(NULL, "hello world", "", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

And this simple pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>lmiguelmh.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>msgbox-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>nar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
                <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <libraries>
                        <library>
                            <type>executable</type>
                            <run>true</run>
                        </library>
                    </libraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In this case I am using the `nar-maven-plugin` version *3.2.3*. I can run `mvn compile` and the artifact `msgbox-app.exe` will be generated successfully.

But when I change the version of the `nar-maven-plugin` to **3.3.0** and I run `mvn compile` I get a lot of errors:

```
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1243) : error C2065: 'SAL_sameIRQL' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1243) : error C2065: 'SAL_sameIRQL' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2513: 'int' : no variable declared before '='
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2513: 'int' : no variable declared before '='
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2377: 'EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION' : redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any other symbol
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1246) : error C2377: 'EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION' : redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any other symbol
[INFO]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\excpt.h(44) : see declaration of 'EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION'
[INFO]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\excpt.h(44) : see declaration of 'EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1252) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1252) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C2365: 'EXCEPTION_ROUTINE' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C2365: 'EXCEPTION_ROUTINE' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
[INFO]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1247) : see declaration of 'EXCEPTION_ROUTINE'
[INFO]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1247) : see declaration of 'EXCEPTION_ROUTINE'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(1254) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(10749) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Handler'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(10749) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Handler'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(10749) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(10749) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(10749) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(10749) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(16638) : error C2144: syntax error : 'PSLIST_ENTRY' should be preceded by ','
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(16638) : error C2144: syntax error : 'PSLIST_ENTRY' should be preceded by ','
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(16646) : error C2144: syntax error : 'PSLIST_ENTRY' should be preceded by ','
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\winnt.h(16646) : error C2144: syntax error : 'PSLIST_ENTRY' should be preceded by ','
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\heapapi.h(124) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_SA_annotes1'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\heapapi.h(124) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '_SA_annotes1'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\heapapi.h(125) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\heapapi.h(125) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\heapapi.h(125) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\heapapi.h(125) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\processthreadsapi.h(204) : error C2144: syntax error : 'LPVOID' should be preceded by ','
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\processthreadsapi.h(204) : error C2144: syntax error : 'LPVOID' should be preceded by ','
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(189) : error C2065: 'SAL_preferredFunction' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(189) : error C2065: 'SAL_preferredFunction' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(192) : error C2448: '_SA_annotes2' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(192) : error C2448: '_SA_annotes2' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(192) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(192) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : error C2065: 'COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : error C2065: 'COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NameType'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NameType'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : error C2491: 'GetComputerNameExA' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(351) : error C2491: 'GetComputerNameExA' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(354) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(354) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : error C2065: 'COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : error C2065: 'COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NameType'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NameType'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : error C2491: 'GetComputerNameExW' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(361) : error C2491: 'GetComputerNameExW' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(364) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(364) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : error C2065: 'COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : error C2065: 'COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NameType'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NameType'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : error C2491: 'SetComputerNameExW' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(383) : error C2491: 'SetComputerNameExW' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(385) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\sysinfoapi.h(385) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(429) : error C2065: 'MEMORY_RESOURCE_NOTIFICATION_TYPE' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(429) : error C2065: 'MEMORY_RESOURCE_NOTIFICATION_TYPE' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NotificationType'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'NotificationType'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : error C2491: 'CreateMemoryResourceNotification' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : error C2491: 'CreateMemoryResourceNotification' : definition of dllimport data not allowed
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(430) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(536) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PWIN32_MEMORY_RANGE_ENTRY'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\memoryapi.h(536) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PWIN32_MEMORY_RANGE_ENTRY'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\threadpoolapiset.h(341) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PTP_WIN32_IO_CALLBACK'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\threadpoolapiset.h(341) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'PTP_WIN32_IO_CALLBACK'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(54) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BEM_FREE_INTERFACE_CALLBACK'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(54) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'BEM_FREE_INTERFACE_CALLBACK'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(64) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(64) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(64) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(64) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(73) : error C2065: 'BEM_REFERENCE' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(73) : error C2065: 'BEM_REFERENCE' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(73) : error C2065: 'reference' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(73) : error C2065: 'reference' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(74) : error C2065: 'BEM_REFERENCE' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(74) : error C2065: 'BEM_REFERENCE' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(75) : error C2065: 'copiedReference' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(75) : error C2065: 'copiedReference' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(75) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(75) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(75) : error C2078: too many initializers
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(75) : error C2078: too many initializers
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(81) : error C2065: 'BEM_REFERENCE' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(81) : error C2065: 'BEM_REFERENCE' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : error C2065: 'reference' : undeclared identifier
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : error C2065: 'reference' : undeclared identifier
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : warning C4229: anachronism used : modifiers on data are ignored
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : error C2182: 'BemFreeReference' : illegal use of type 'void'
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : error C2182: 'BemFreeReference' : illegal use of type 'void'
[INFO] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
[ERROR] C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um\bemapiset.h(82) : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

**Update**
Maybe the problem is the difference 1) in the way is searching for Visual Studio (in my case I have msvc9 and msvc11) 2) in the way of the compiler getting called:

**For 3.2.3**

```
[DEBUG] cl  /c /nologo /EHsc /DNDEBUG /MD /GR /DWindows /DWIN32 /IE:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\src\main\include E:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\src\main\c\main.cpp
[DEBUG] Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'cl' with arguments:
''
'/c'
'/nologo'
'/EHsc'
'/DNDEBUG'
'/MD'
'/GR'
'/DWindows'
'/DWIN32'
'/IE:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\src\main\include'
'E:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\src\main\c\main.cpp'
```

**For 3.3.0**

```
[DEBUG] "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl"  /c /nologo /EHsc /DNDEBUG /MD /GR /DWIN32 /IE:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\target\nar\obj\x86-Windows-msvc /IE:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\target\nar\obj\x86-Windows-msvc /IE:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\src\main\include "/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include" "/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include" "/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um" "/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared" "/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt" /FoE:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\target\nar\obj\x86-Windows-msvc\main.c1e925e5.obj c/main.cpp
[DEBUG] Setting environment variable: PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem
[DEBUG] Setting environment variable: SystemRoot=C:\windows
[DEBUG] Setting environment variable: TMP=C:\Users\lmamani\AppData\Local\Temp
[DEBUG] Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl' with arguments:
''
'/c'
'/nologo'
'/EHsc'
'/DNDEBUG'
'/MD'
'/GR'
'/DWIN32'
'/IE:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\target\nar\obj\x86-Windows-msvc'
'/IE:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\target\nar\obj\x86-Windows-msvc'
'/IE:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\src\main\include'
'/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include'
'/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include'
'/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um'
'/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared'
'/IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt'
'/FoE:\PROY\test\dev\1.0\msgbox-app\target\nar\obj\x86-Windows-msvc\main.c1e925e5.obj'
'c/main.cpp'
```

*Important: This question's last updates could be found in https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/issues/217*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said the problem was a functionality added to the Maven NAR Plugin. The original answer was posted by GregDomjan on github and could be found here:

[Maven NAR Plugin: Compiler errors in a simple program that uses Windows.h in version 3.3.0](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/issues/217)

*TLDR:* You need to use the latest version of the plugin (3.3.0) and modify your configuration according your environment (in my case msvc11.0/winsdk8.0):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.maven-nar</groupId>
            <artifactId>nar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <libraries>
                    <library>
                        <type>executable</type>
                        <run>true</run>
                    </library>
                </libraries>
                <msvc>
                    <version>11.0</version>
                    <windowsSdkVersion>8.0</windowsSdkVersion>
                </msvc>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```